# Backup with Time Machine on WD My Book live fails

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, time-machine

Directly after buying this baby I had no problems using the built-in Time Machine compatibility. Then the problems began. Back then I wasn’t able to associate an application directly with the failing of the backup. I worked around the problem using the hacks to use any NAS as a Time Machine backup volume.

However, a few days ago I bought a new iMac and after copying over my data and installing all the applications I use I wanted to setup the Time Machine backup. Unfortunately I had no further luck than the last time, the same errors (error 17 and error -6508 while creating the Sparsebundle) occurred. For testing purposes I set up my "old" iMac anew and… the backup works perfectly. My old machine was just setup with OS X 10.6, all the updates available and iLife '11. There the backup works, on my new machine with a newly created user profile it fails.

I’m running such applications as MacFUSE and Total Finder which are known to integrate very deeply into the operating system. I disabled those, still no luck. Then I started killing background processes, but still… no luck.

I’d love to hear your ideas as I don’t know any further. Thanks.

Comment: It's possible you have a permissions issue of you used your external hard drive with another machine. Can you manually, in Finder, create files and folders on the backup disk, or in the folder named `Backups.backupdb`? If not, check to see if you can disable ownership on that volume, make your user account on your new Mac the owner of all files on there, or, if all that fails, reformat the backup volume and start anew.

Comment: The My Book live is a NAS with integrated functionality for Time Machine compatibility. During the initial setup of the backup I can choose only one remote volume, My Book-backup, that’s it. http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/UM/DEU/4779-705042.pdf

Comment: Oh sorry, this is the German manual. Here’s the English one: http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/UM/ENG/4779-705042.pdf In this manual you have a section regarding the Mac and Time Machine.

Comment: But you do have access to the volume you selected as backup destination in the Finder? Und ich kann übrigens deutsch obwohl ich Schwabe bin ;)

Comment: Hab deinen Namen nicht gelesen, sorry ;-). No, I can’t access the share shown in the Finder, but this is the same on the other Mac where the backup works perfectly.